# Kill process by seeing the console messages via perl script

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I have script which displays following messages on the console whenever a script runs in perforce. The messages are as follows:

```
35000 P4V/2010.1/2010.1/260003/v67 R yzhao      dfasfd     00:00:04 IDLE none   

45000 unnamed p4-python script/v71 10.4.16.60     R integration 06:40:38 IDLE none
```

Please can you suggest how to kill the 45000 process and not the 35000 process as the second process contains R integration in the line. Also, they are not getting saved in any file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
 print qx(kill -9 45000); # assuming you are signed in as yzhao
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a script which individually distributes the variables as per regex of the above line mentioned. But I want to know how can I store the console messages so that the perl script runs on it. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: yourscript | tee  datafile.txt ; then read from datafile.txt and do your kill process